# How to manage complex state behaviour on my Vue.js checkbox component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a couple of challenges that I am trying to overcome in my 1 week of learning Vue.js. Please note that this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/spqdkLve/8/) is in reality wrapped around a parent component called `<question>` which isn't that interesting, so I have kept my code simplified for this post.

1. How can I set certain items to be default checked on load?

**Edit — I figured 1 out. Just had to do `[ "Chicken", "Turkey", "Beef", "Fish", "Pork" ]`**

2. How can I uncheck certain items like if I select Vegan, meat options should be unchecked?
3. How do I have an Exclude and Include checkbox alongside my options?

[image]

**Checkbox**

```
<div id="questionnaire">
  <checkbox v-model="form.meats" id="8a"  option="Chicken"></checkbox>
  <checkbox v-model="form.meats" id="8b" option="Turkey"></checkbox>
  <checkbox v-model="form.meats" id="8c" option="Beef"></checkbox>
  <checkbox v-model="form.meats" id="8d" option="Pork"></checkbox>
  <checkbox v-model="form.meats" id="8e" option="Fish"></checkbox>
  <checkbox v-model="form.meats" id="8f" option="Vegetarian Only"></checkbox>
  <checkbox v-model="form.meats" id="8g" option="Vegan Only"></checkbox>
  {{ form.meats }}
</div>
```

**Vue.component('checkbox')**

```
Vue.component('checkbox', {
  template: `
    <div>
            <input type="checkbox" :id="id" :value="option" v-model="checked" @change="update">
            <label :for="id">
                {{ option }}
                <slot></slot>
            </label>
    </div>
    `,
  data() {
    return {
      checkedProxy: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    checked: {
      get() {
        return this.value
      },
      set(option) {
        this.checkedProxy = option
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    update: function(e) {
      this.$emit('input', this.checkedProxy)
    }
  },
  props: {
    value: null,
    option: null,
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#questionnaire",
  data: {

    form: {

      meats: [],

    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Did You check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865348/vuejs-set-a-radio-button-checked-if-statement-is-true

Comment: Doesn't help for 2 or 3. 1 I figured out already. Besides, mine's a checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these are what you want.

```
<div id="questionnaire">
  <check-group :chks="chks" v-model="form.meats"></check-group>
  {{ form.meats }}
</div>

const groups = {
    '1': {
        tag: 'meats',
        exclusiveGroups: [2]
    },
    '2': {
        tag: 'vegan',
        exclusiveGroups: [1]
    }
}

const chks = {
    'Chicken': {
        groupIds: [1]
    },
    'Turkey': {
        groupIds: [1]
    },
    'Beef': {
        groupIds: [1]
    },
    'Pork': {
        groupIds: [1]
    },
    'Fish': {
        groupIds: [1]
    },
    'Vegetarian Only': {
        groupIds: [2]
    },
    'Vegan Only': {
        groupIds: [2]
    }
}

Vue.component('checkbox', {
    template: `
    <div>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ref="chk" :value="val" v-model="value" @change="update($event)">
            {{ txt }}
            <slot></slot>
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" :checked="value.indexOf(val)<0" @change="reverseSelection($event)">
    </div>
    `,
    data () {
        return {
            val: this.optValue || this.optText,
            txt: this.optText || this.optValue
        }
    },
    methods: {
        update (e) {
            this.$emit('input', this.value, e.target.value, e.target.checked)
        },
        reverseSelection () {
            var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            e.initEvent("click", true, true);
            this.$refs.chk.dispatchEvent(e);
        }
    },
    props: ['value','optValue','optText']
});

Vue.component('check-group',{
    template: `
        <div>
            <checkbox v-for="item in chks" :opt-value="item.value" :opt-text="item.text" @input="update" v-model="value"></checkbox>
        </div>
    `,
    props: {
        value: {
            required: true,
            type: Array
        },
        chks: {
            required: true,
            type: Array
        }
    },
    methods: {
        update (val,curVal,checked) {
            if(checked){//only checkbox be checked need to judge mutually-exclusive
                chks[curVal].groupIds.forEach(id=>{//iterate all group of this checkbox
                    groups[id].exclusiveGroups.forEach(eid=>{//iterate all exclusiveGroups of this group
                        for(let i=0;i<val.length;i++){
                            let p = chks[val[i]].groupIds.indexOf(eid)
                            if(p>=0){//if this checkbox's group in exclusiveGroups then remove this item from val Array
                                val.splice(p,1)
                                i--
                            }
                        }
                    })
                })
            }
            this.$emit('input',val)
        },
    }
})

new Vue({
    el: "#questionnaire",
    data: {
        chks: Object.keys(chks).map(key=>({value: key,groupIds: chks[key]})),
        form: {
            meats: ['Chicken']
        }
    }
})
```

if you want to let vegan and vegetarian can't be both selected at once,
you can modify defining of groups and chks like this:

```
const groups = {
    '1': {
        tag: 'meats',
        exclusiveGroups: [2] //means that when the checkbox of this group be checked,the checkbox whose group-index equals 2 where be unchecked
    },
    '2': {
        tag: 'vegan',
        exclusiveGroups: [1,3]
    },
    '3': {
        tag: 'Vegetarian Only',
        exclusiveGroups: [1,2]
    }
}

const chks = {
    'Chicken': {
        groupIds: [1]
    },
    'Turkey': {
        groupIds: [1]
    },
    'Beef': {
        groupIds: [1]
    },
    'Pork': {
        groupIds: [1]
    },
    'Fish': {
        groupIds: [1]
    },
    'Vegetarian Only': {
        groupIds: [3]
    },
    'Vegan Only': {
        groupIds: [2]
    }
}
```

Comment: Sweet, but helps to understand how it works. Also, vegan and vegetarian can't be both selected at once :)

Comment: groupIds in chks means this checkbox's group (can mutiple)
and const groups stores the group info
and exclusiveGroups in groups means what groups mutually-exclusive with this group

Comment: How can I ensure if Meat options are selected, Vegetarian gets deselected. Same as behaviour as Vegan one.

Comment: just set their groupIds and exclusiveGroups

Comment: Thanks. What is this `this.$refs.chk.dispatchEvent(e);` line of code doing exactly?

Comment: Also, my development version says `v-for` should have `keys`. How'd I go about that one?

Comment: this.$refs.chk used to get dom reference of that checkbox,and dispatchEvent(e) can trigger 'onclick' event of the checkbox.just like you click on that checkbox

Comment: and question about 'v-for',you can bind a 'key' for erery checkbox
just like this:
            <checkbox v-for="item in chks" :key="item.value" :opt-value="item.value" :opt-text="item.text" @input="update" v-model="value"></checkbox>
here need a unique key for vue to operat the dom element

Comment: More serious issue is `avoid mutating a prop` error. It is the `value` prop