# Vue.js radio button not checked by default

Tags: vue.js, radio-button

I'd like to make default checked on radio buttons inside a `v-for` loop. 
Here is the code:

```
  <ul v-for="p in photos">
        <li>
          <div>

          <div>
            <div>
              Visibility: {{p.visible}}
            </div>                


            <strong>Visibility setting</strong><br>
            <input type="radio" v-model="p.visible" name="visibility" value="all" :checked="p.visible == 'all'"> All <br>
            <input type="radio" v-model="p.visible" name="visibility" value="fav" :checked="p.visible == 'fav'"> My favorites <br>
            <input type="radio" v-model="p.visible" name="visibility" value="none" :checked="p.visible == 'none'"> No one

          </div>
            <div><img" v-bind:src="BASE_URL +'/uploads/' + userId + '/'+ p.imgId" /> </div>
        </div>          


      </li>

      </ul>
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34865436/5774375) answer.

While I can see `Visibility` of each item is being printed, the default radio buttons of each photo are not checked as expected.

Here is the `photos` array which I receive from the server when the component is created:

```
   [ 
        {
            "id" : "5bcebb6efeaea3147b7a22f0",
            "imgId" : "12710.png",
            "visible" : "all"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "5bcebbf0feaea3147b7a22f1",
            "imgId" : "62818.png",
            "visible" : "fav"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "5bcec010feaea3147b7a22f2",
            "imgId" : "36740.png",
            "visible" : "none"
        }
    ],
```

What is wrong here and how can I fix it?

Comment: what if you remove the :checked attributes from input field ?

Comment: Add console log

Comment: @EmtiazZahid nothing is checked then.

Comment: @NickSavenia What in the console would you like to see? There is no error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue.js default radio button checked does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52974506/vue-js-default-radio-button-checked-does-not-work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Don't use `:checked`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html):

> `v-model` will ignore the initial `value`, `checked` or `selected` attributes found on any form elements. It will always treat the Vue instance data as the source of truth. You should declare the initial value on the JavaScript side, inside the `data` option of your component.

If `v-model` is the same as `value` it will return true for that checkbox. Your fixed fiddle:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    photos: [{
        "id": "5bcebb6efeaea3147b7a22f0",
        "imgId": "12710.png",
        "visible": "all"
      },
      {
        "id": "5bcebbf0feaea3147b7a22f1",
        "imgId": "62818.png",
        "visible": "fav"
      },
      {
        "id": "5bcec010feaea3147b7a22f2",
        "imgId": "36740.png",
        "visible": "none"
      }
    ],
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">

  <ul v-for="(p, index) in photos">
    <li>

      <div>
        Visibility: {{p.visible}}
      </div>

      <strong>Visibility setting</strong><br>
      <input type="radio" v-model="photos[index].visible" :name=`visibility-${index}` value="all"> All <br>
      <input type="radio" v-model="photos[index].visible" :name=`visibility-${index}` value="fav"> My favorites <br>
      <input type="radio" v-model="photos[index].visible" :name=`visibility-${index}` value="none"> No one

    </li>
  </ul>



</div>
```

Now each radio group has it's own `name`, with `v-model` targeting that group (note the `index`).

Comment: Just to add something - `name` property is also messing with the default `checked` state. I was using custom radio group controller and realized that when each input has `:name="name"` prop, Vue would ignore initial default value. Removing `:name` prop solved my issue