# Vue.JS radio input without v-model

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a component that takes an array of options objects, a name, and a v-model, and puts out a radio input with matching label for each of the options in that array of options.

```
options = [
    {text: "Option 1", value="option-1" },
    {text: "Option 2", value="option-2" },
]


"updateValue" : function(){
    this.$emit('input', this.$refs.input.value);
}

<template v-for="option in options" >
    <input 
        :value="option.value" 
        :id="name + option.value" 
        :name="name" 
        @input="updateValue()"
        ref="input" />
    <label :for="name + option.value">{{option.text}}</label>
</template>
```

I've found a similar pattern in [this guide](https://alligator.io/vuejs/add-v-model-support/) where a v-model is taken and then value emitted by watching the `@input` event.

I cannot wrap my head around how to do this with a radio-type input. Setting `:value="value"` as with say a text input would make all the radio values identical, which really doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34865436/1113204

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of a really primitive radio button component that uses `v-model` to update data when an entry is clicked:

```js
const radio = {
  props: ['option', 'value'],
  template: `<div @click="onClick">{{ option === value ? 'o' : 'x' }}<slot /></div>`,

  methods: {
    onClick () {
      this.$emit('input', this.option)
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  components: {
    radio
  },

  data () {
    return {
      options: ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
      selectedOption: 'red'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <radio v-for="option in options"
    v-model="selectedOption"
    :option="option"
  >
    {{ option }}
  </radio>
</div>
```

With this implementation each radio button is passed both the currently selected value (via `v-model`) as well as the value for that particular option (via `option`). It uses `===` inside each radio button to determine whether it is the currently selected option.

Vue's support for native radio button's is described here:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Radio

It is effectively the same as my example except that what I've called `option` it calls `value`. Don't be confused by the way it uses both `v-model` and `value`. While `v-model` binds to `value` and `input` by default it can actually be bound to any prop and event (see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#model). In the case of native checkboxes and radio buttons it binds to the `checked` property and the `change` event (mentioned in https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage).

**Update:**

I think I may have misunderstood your question. My answer provides relevant background but it may be backwards for what you want. `v-model` just expands to a prop and an event, so if you want to replace `v-model` with something else you just need to find out which prop and event it's using and use those directly instead.