# radio checked between 2 values

Tags: vue.js, prestashop

I am modifying a module on Prestashop (Blockwishlist) which uses VueJS and I want to add the available combinations in the customers' wish list in order to be able to select a combination and add it to the cart.

But I'm stuck on a part when loading the page: I get the `id_product` and the `id_product_attribute` and I also loop on all the variations of the product.
**I am looking for a checked radio button** by comparing the values ​​of my loop and the `id_product_attribute` value that I get back and if it exists in my loop this checked the radio button.

This is what my vuejs code looks like now (with attempts that don't work)

```html
    <template>
      <div class="wishlist-product">
        <a
          class="wishlist-product-link"
          :href="product.canonical_url"
        >
          <div class="wishlist-product-image">
            <img
              v-if="product.default_image"
              :src="product.default_image.large.url"
              :alt="product.default_image.legend"
              :title="product.default_image.legend"
              :class="{
                'wishlist-product-unavailable': !product.add_to_cart_url
              }"
            >
            <img
              v-else
              :src="prestashop.urls.no_picture_image.bySize.home_default.url"
            >
          </div>
          <div class="wishlist-product-right">
            <p class="wishlist-product-title">{{ product.name }}</p>
    
            <p class="wishlist-product-price">
              <span
                class="wishlist-product-price-promo"
                v-if="product.has_discount"
              >
                {{ product.regular_price }}
              </span>
              {{ product.price }}
            </p>
    
            <div class="wishlist-product-combinations">
              <div class="product-variants">
                <div class="clearfix product-variants-item">
                  <div id="group_1" class="radio">
                    <div v-for="(attribute, key, index) of product.all_attributes" class="input-container float-xs-left"
                         :class="{'no_stock_variant' : attribute.quantity <= 0}">
                      <label>
                        <input
                          @change="changeAttribute($event)"
                          v-model="id_product_attribute"
                          name="id_product_attribute"
                          class="input-radio" type="radio"
                          :data-id-product=attribute.id_product
                          :data-id-product-attribute=attribute.id_product_attribute
                          :data-product-attribute=attribute.id_attribute
                          :value="key"
                          v-if="checkedId(attribute.id_product_attribute) ? 'checked=checked' : ''"
                          :title=attribute.attribute_name>
                        <div class="content">
                            <span class="radio-label">
                              {{ attribute.attribute_name }}
                              <img v-if="attribute.quantity <= 0"
                                   :src="imgEnveloppe"
                                   :class="{hover: isHovering}"
                                   @mouseover="imgEnveloppe = imgRing"
                                   @mouseout="isHovering = false"
                                   :alt="attribute.attribute_name"
                              >
                            </span>
                        </div>
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="wishlist-product-bottom">
          <button
            class="btn btn-indies-gold wishlist-button-add"
            v-if="!isShare"
            @click="removeFromWishlist"
          >
            {{ deleteText }}
          </button>
          <button
            class="btn btn-indies wishlist-product-addtocart"
            :disabled="isDisabled"
            @click="
              product.add_to_cart_url || product.customizable === '1'
                ? addToCartAction()
                : null
            "
          >
            {{ product.customizable === '1' ? customizeText : addToCart }}
          </button>
        </div>
    
        <p
          class="wishlist-product-availability wishlist-product-availability-responsive"
          v-if="product.show_availability"
        >
          <i
            class="material-icons"
            v-if="product.availability === 'unavailable'"
          >
            block
          </i>
          <i
            class="material-icons"
            v-if="product.availability === 'last_remaining_items'"
          >
            warning
          </i>
          {{ product.availability_message }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import EventBus from '@components/EventBus';
    import headers from '@constants/headers';
    import prestashop from 'prestashop';
    import wishlistAddProductToCartUrl from 'wishlistAddProductToCartUrl';
    
    export default {
      name: 'Product',
      props: {
        product: {
          type: Object,
          required: true,
          default: null,
        },
        deleteText: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        imgEnveloppe: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        imgRing: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        listId: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
          default: null,
        },
        isShare: {
          type: Boolean,
          required: false,
          default: false,
        },
        customizeText: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
          default: 'Customize',
        },
        quantityText: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
          default: 'Quantity',
        },
        addToCart: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        status: {
          type: Number,
          required: false,
          default: 0,
        },
        hasControls: {
          type: Boolean,
          required: false,
          default: true,
        },
      },
      data() {
        return {
          prestashop,
          isHovering: false,
          id_product_attribute: null
        };
      },
      computed: {
        isDisabled() {
          if (this.product.customizable === '1') {
            return false;
          }
    
          return !this.product.add_to_cart_url;
        },
      },
      methods: {
        checkedId (idProductAttribute) {
          if (this.product.id_product_attribute === parseInt(idProductAttribute)) {
            console.log(idProductAttribute);
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        },
        changeAttribute(e) {
          this.id_product_attribute = e.target.getAttribute('data-id-product-attribute');
        },
        /**
         * Remove the product from the wishlist
         */
        async removeFromWishlist() {
          EventBus.$emit('showDeleteWishlist', {
            detail: {
              listId: this.listId,
              productId: this.product.id,
              productAttributeId: this.product.id_product_attribute,
            },
          });
        },
        async addToCartAction() {
          if (this.product.add_to_cart_url && this.product.customizable !== '1') {
            try {
              const datas = new FormData();
              datas.append('qty', this.product.wishlist_quantity);
              datas.append('id_product', this.product.id_product);
              datas.append('id_product_attribute', this.id_product_attribute);
              datas.append('id_customization', this.product.id_customization);
    
              const response = await fetch(
                `${this.product.add_to_cart_url}&action=update`,
                {
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: headers.addToCart,
                  body: datas,
                },
              );
    
              const resp = await response.json();
    
              prestashop.emit('updateCart', {
                reason: {
                  idProduct: this.product.id_product,
                  idProductAttribute: this.id_product_attribute,
                  idCustomization: this.product.id_customization,
                  linkAction: 'add-to-cart',
                },
                resp,
              });
    
              /* eslint-disable */
              const statResponse = await fetch(
                `${wishlistAddProductToCartUrl}&params[idWishlist]=${this.listId}&params[id_product]=${this.product.id_product}&params[id_product_attribute]=${this.id_product_attribute}&params[quantity]=${this.product.wishlist_quantity}`,
                {
                  headers: {
                    'Content-Type':
                      'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                    Accept: 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01'
                  }
                }
              );
              /* eslint-enable */
    
              await statResponse.json();
            } catch (error) {
              prestashop.emit('handleError', {
                eventType: 'addProductToCart',
                resp: error,
              });
            }
          } else {
            window.location.href = this.product.canonical_url;
          }
        },
      },
    };
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: I think the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865348/vuejs-set-a-radio-button-checked-if-statement-is-true will also answer your question.